# How to multiply two columns and store their result in single column and then do the sum of new column generated?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two column Price and quantity. I have multiplied them

```
select Price*Quantity as SubTotal from ProductInfo
```

and now i want to do the sum of all rows in subtotal as grandtotal

```
SUM(SubTotal) as GrandTotal
```

and
therefore a new query like this

```
select Price*Quantity as SubTotal , SUM(SubTotal) as GrandTotal from ProductInfo
```

how can i do this please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead::

```
Select Price*Quantity as SubTotal, 
SUM(Price*Quantity) as GrandTotal 
from ProductInfo
```

This will result as expected.

Comment: will it do the sum of all rows of subtotal

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'ProductInfo.Price' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ISNULL(Price*Quantity, 'GrandTotal') as SubTotal, 
SUM(Price*Quantity) as Total 
from ProductInfo
GROUP BY   ISNULL(Price*Quantity, 'GrandTotal')
WITH ROLLUP
```